# Spring Security 4 - Allow Access To Controller And Authenticate Everything Else

Tags: spring-4

I was following this [github project](https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth) to familiarize myself with Spring Security. I have the project up and running as is. I made a small modification to the OAuth2ServerConfiguration.java file trying to allow access to a controller and authenticating everything else. I'm not sure if it's possible to do this with 2 rules or not, here is the code in question:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/homecontroller").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/greeting").authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

The code above works fine, when I change `"/greeting"` to `/**`, everything requires authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old question, but since than I have spent quite a bit of time getting familiar with Spring Security (I'm not an expert...).

In Spring Security you can have multiple `HttpSecurity` configurations in the same `configure()` methods. It is important to keep in mind that the order of the `antMatchers` and rules is important. Spring Security will find the first match and go from there, it will not run through the remaining matches to determine which is the best one to use.